# web3.py SendTransaction only in pending

Tags: ethereum, web3py, go-ethereum

I wonder why all the Txs send with the method `web3.eth.sendTransaction({})`in my private network to a node ending up in the pending section of the txpool. Why aren't they counted in the queued-section? what are the differences betweend pending and queued? and how do i get the tx queued instead of pending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want your transactions to go in the `queued` section. Pending is where they wait, until a miner includes it in the next block. Sounds like your private network miner is not including your transactions.

For more about pending vs queued, see: [What is the difference between a pending transaction and a queued transaction in the geth mempool?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9137/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pending-transaction-and-a-queued-transaction-in)

> Pending transactions are transactions that are ready to be processed and included in the block.
>
> Queued transactions are transactions where the transaction nonce is not in sequence. The transaction nonce is an incrementing number for each transaction with the same From address.